How to save files ( 200 mb size ) in indexdb or in client side in react app
Developing document processing application in react in which need to download the word or pdf in client side and process that file . To avoid roundtrip to server i am trying to save the document in indexdb , but it is giving out of storage exception when try to save document of 100 mb
to get the document i am using xmlhttprequest and onsuccess i am trying to save in indexdb so that i can use in react component ( using syncfusion pdfviewer component (client side ) )
When the file size is more than 100 mb ( I am expecting size upto 150 mb ) it fails by saying indexdb full.
I know indexdb capacity is based on hard disk capacity , I am not sure how to allocate 1gb of space for indexdb.
